# Pattern matching in regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have below dictionary that I created in such a way that the key is the length of the values.

```
{4: {'lost', 'lust', 'list', 'last', 'lest', 'blue'}, 5: {'beryl'}, 8: {'blowlamp', 'blimbing', 'bluejays', 'jigsawed'}, 9: {'blistered', 'oospheres', 'blackcaps', 'blastular', 'blotchier', 'troweller'}, 10: {'blancmange', 'blackguard', 'volcanizes'}, 6: {'blague', 'blacks', 'blonde', 'blocks'}, 7: {'blawort', 'blinder', 'blender', 'blonder', 'blunder', 'blander'}}
```

I want to pull out a list of values in this dictionary in such a way that the vowel comes at the same place for 5 words like
[lost,lust,list,last,lest],[blinder,blender,blonder,blunder,blander]]

I am not having any idea on how to get the list in such a way. One way I thought could be through regex but on what basis do I match? The length of the words could be anything and vowel could be anywhere.

PS this is a codewars question. https://www.codewars.com/kata/vowel-alternations/train/python
My approach so far that I got the values with same length in a dictionary so that I can work on the values. I just have no idea how to work on the values. 
It would be helpful if anyone can explain me what they are thinking and what is the best way to do this.

The rest of the code

```
mdict={}
rev_multidict = {}

for i in words:
    for sublist in i:
        mdict[sublist] = len(sublist)
    for key, value in mdict.items():
        rev_multidict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

for key,value in rev_multidict.items():
    i = rev_multidict[key]
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the first string for the location of the vowels and generate a regex string to match. Every char maps to either '[aeiou]' or '.' depending on if it's a vowel or not. Why you do with 'y' is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print out only if the output list contains 5 words:

```
text = {4: {'lost', 'lust', 'list', 'last', 'lest', 'blue'}, 5: {'beryl'}, 8: {'blowlamp', 'blimbing', 'bluejays', 'jigsawed'}, 9: {'blistered', 'oospheres', 'blackcaps', 'blastular', 'blotchier', 'troweller'}, 10: {'blancmange', 'blackguard', 'volcanizes'}, 6: {'blague', 'blacks', 'blonde', 'blocks'}, 7: {'blawort', 'blinder', 'blender', 'blonder', 'blunder', 'blander'}}
vowels = "aeiou"
for i in range(4,10):
        words = text[i]
        rep_idx = []
        for word in words:
            for letter in vowels:
                if letter in word:
                    idx = word.index(letter)
                    if idx not in rep_idx:
                        word_list = []
                        for word in words:
                            if word[idx] in vowels:
                                word_list.append(word)
                        if len(word_list) == 5:
                            print ("{}, Vowel Index: {}".format(word_list, idx))
                    rep_idx.append(idx)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
['lust', 'lest', 'list', 'lost', 'last'], Vowel Index: 1
['blonder', 'blender', 'blinder', 'blander', 'blunder'], Vowel Index: 5
['blistered', 'blackcaps', 'troweller', 'blastular', 'blotchier'], Vowel Index: 2
['blistered', 'troweller', 'oospheres', 'blastular', 'blotchier'], Vowel Index: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is the start of one way of approaching it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

words = 'last lest best list '.split()
words1 = 'blander wigwam blunder slender'.split()

print("word list one: {}".format(words))
print('')
aoa = [re.split('[aeiou]', word) for word in words]
for item in aoa:
    print(item)

print('\n')

print("word list two: {}".format(words1))
print('')
aoa1 = [re.split('[aeiou]', word) for word in words1]
for item in aoa1:
    print(item)
```

the output is:

```
word list one: ['last', 'lest', 'best', 'list']

['l', 'st']
['l', 'st']
['b', 'st']
['l', 'st']


word list two: ['blander', 'wigwam', 'blunder', 'slender']

['bl', 'nd', 'r']
['w', 'gw', 'm']
['bl', 'nd', 'r']
['sl', 'nd', 'r']
```

The regex splits on vowels. If you look closely at the output of the split, you will notice that for the words that should match, the corresponding list index values are the same. Perhaps you can iterate over the lists and do a comparison.

That is left up to you...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for the codewars Question (I've taken different approach than you, so I didn't use your code):

First you define a simple function changing all vowels for some (here a dollar sign) character:

```
from collections import Counter
def translate(word):
    for ch in 'eyuioa':
        if ch in word:
            word=word.replace(ch,'$')
    return word
```

Then you define a function, that takes list of words as an input (eg. ['last', 'lest', 'list', 'lost', 'lust'])) that counts occurences of each translated word, and find that translated word that occurs 5 times. Store it in a list and add a [None] just in case the list is empty (word not found), so that you don't get an error. Then simply print all words that meet a condition.

```
def find_solutions(input_list):
    tuples_list = list(map(lambda x: (x,translate(x)),input_list))
    counting = Counter(map(lambda x: x[1], tuples_list))
    desired_pattern = [x for x,y in dict(counting).items() if y ==5] + [None]
    return  [x for x, y in tuples_list if y==desired_pattern[0]]
```

example:

```
find_solutions(['last', 'lest', 'list', 'lost', 'lust'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be very robust approach, but it seems to work:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

def find_solutions(words):
    solutions = []
    vowel_list = list(vowels)
    cases = []
    for word in words:
        for i, l in enumerate(word):
            if l in vowel_list:
                c = list(word)
                temp = []
                for vowel in vowel_list:
                    c[i] = vowel
                    temp.append(''.join(c))
                cases.append(temp)
    for case in cases:
        if all([item in words for item in case]):
            if case not in solutions:
                solutions.append(case)
    return solutions
```